# IIS URL Rewrite for modifying query parameter on outbound redirect response

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to figure out a way to modify a single query string parameter within the Location header of a HTTP 302 Found (redirect) response.

For example, if the Location header in the response is:

```
https://example.com/path?param1=a&param2=z&param3=c
```

I would like it to be rewritten as:

```
https://example.com/path?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c
```

Is this possible using an outbound IIS URL Rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule to achieve your requirement.

```
<outboundRules>
    <!-- This rule changes the domain in the HTTP location header for redirection responses -->
    <rule name="Change Location Header">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^https://example.com/path?param1=a&param2=(.+)&param3=c" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="https://example.com/path?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c"/>
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```